# Calculation is NOT coming correctly when i use Double?

Tags: groovy, soapui

```
groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Product_Search#ResponseAsXml")
deliveryPrice=holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:Response/ns1:deliveryPrice")
def itemPrice=holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:Response/itemprice")
//Qty=context.testCase.getPropertyValue("quantity").toInteger()
def Qty=5
log.info(Qty)
totalPrice= itemPrice.toDouble()*Qty
log.info(totalPrice)
```

My item price is 17.99 and Qty is 5

Expecting: 89.95

But getting *   Tue Sep 30 08:10:59 BST 2014:INFO:89.94999999999999

Due to which my assertion is failed..

How to resolve this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due the `double` precision in java. When you use `17.99` the value you get for your `double` is the closest double-precision value to it (see [primitive data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [floating point types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) for more info). If you want the exact decimal representation use [`BigDecimal` instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

`totalPrice= itemPrice.toBigDecimal()*Qty`

instead of:

`totalPrice= itemPrice.toDouble()*Qty`

Hope this helps,

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html and http://floating-point-gui.de/ seem relevant too ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates good explanation resource, as usual your comment is very useful! thanks `:)`.